# Kendo datepicker is showing as empty in IE if min and max values are set

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm using kendo date picker to select a date in my project. But it is not working properly in IE. If I set the min and max values for the date picker then it will show an empty calendar in IE. I'm using IE-11.

Sample code

```
$(".datepicker:last").kendoDatePicker({
      max: new Date(endDate),
      min: new Date(startDate),
      format: "yyyy/MM/dd"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this fiddle [jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/gx3h1sxu/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/gx3h1sxu/1/)

Its working fine in *IE* also with min and max option

```
var startDate=new Date('1/1/2000');
var endDate=new Date('1/1/2020');
$(".datepicker:last").kendoDatePicker({
      max: new Date(endDate),
      min: new Date(startDate),
      format: "yyyy/MM/dd"
   });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Got the answer. I was using comma(",") as the separator(01,01,2017). It worked in chrome but not in IE. Using "/" as the separator solved the issue in all browsers.